# Finding solutions of modulus functions

Tags: functions, absolute-value

I decided to do some practice with some functions, and was posed with the following question:

[image]

So, I sketched the two graphs. For convenience I'll display a photo of them from Desmos.

[image]

The blue line is |$3x - 2$| and the red is |$x-5$|.

Now, to find when the two intersect, it the case where the two equations have the same output with the same input is achieved.

However, the modulus sign seemed to trip me up when I was writing |$3x - 2$| = |$x-5$| and begin doing algebra. I couldn't merely solve it like the function had no modulus sign, since that is a different function. So, I figured by inspection that only the left side of the red function makes the intersections, so the following conditions are the only valid ones.

$$-x-5 = 3x-2$$

$$-x-5 = -3x+2$$

And with that I can find the inputs necessary.

However, is there a general way to solve this type of problem? Say, if I didn't have the graph to make the inference that I did? How could I solve this problem if *I couldn't* graph the two functions?

Comment: Remember that $|x|=2$ has *two* solutions....if you have $|x-a|=|x-b|$ you would necessarily have *four* scenarios to tackle, in lieu of the nature of $(a, b)$.

Comment: Your method using the graph is a right strategy. There is no good "pure algebra" solution. The graph is a good place to start, but you can see  without the graph that you should consider several cases, depending on whether $x$ is is larger or smaller than $5$ and larger or smaller than $2/3$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$. So
$$|x-5|=|3x-2|\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{(x-5)^2}=\sqrt{(3x-2)^2}.$$

> Lemma:If $x,y>0$, then $x=y$ if and only if $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y}$.

Since $(x-5)^2>0$ and $(3x-2)^2>0$, it follows by the above lemma, we have
$$|x-5|=|3x-2|\Leftrightarrow (x-5)^2=(3x-2)^2.$$
It leads to $$(3x-2)^2-(x-5)^2=(3x-2+x-5)(3x-2-(x-5))=(4x-7)(3x+3)=0.$$
Obvioulsy, the equation has and only has two real solutions, $$x_1=\frac{7}{4} \text{ and }x_2=-\frac{3}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this algebraically would probably be to split the functions up into piecewise functions. Let's say:

$f(x)=|x-5|$

$g(x)=|3x-2|$

First, we need to know where the functions will cross over the x-axis. $f(x)$ crosses the x-axis at $x=5$, while $g(x)$ crosses over at $x=\frac{2}{3}$. We also know that both functions normally increase when there is no absolute value. This means the right-halves of the functions are unchanged, while the left-halves of the functions are reflected over the x-axis from negative to positive. This gives us 4 piecewise functions:

$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
-(x-5), & x \le 5 \\
x-5,  & x \ge 5
\end{cases}$

$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
-(3x-2), & x \le \frac{2}{3}\\
3x-2, & x \ge \frac{2}{3}
\end{cases}$

Now, the next step is to figure out where each piece of one function intersects the pieces of the other function. Let's start with the piece $-(x-5)$, and see where it intersects the pieces of $g(x)$.

$-(x-5)=-(3x-2)\\
2x=-3\\
x=\frac{-3}{2}$

**Intersection point: $(\frac{-3}{2},\frac{13}{2})$**

$-(x-5)=3x-2\\
4x=7\\
x=\frac{7}{4}$

**Intersection point: $(\frac{7}{4},\frac{13}{4})$**

Now, for the piece $x-5$:

$x-5=-(3x-2)\\
4x=7\\
x=\frac{7}{4}$

However, we cannot plug this in, because doing that would yield a point with a negative y-value, which is restricted by the absolute value function. Therefore, there is no solution here.

$x-5=3x-2\\
2x=-3\\
x=\frac{-3}{2}$

This is a similar situation. By plugging in the x-value, we get a point with a negative y-value, which is not allowed by the absolute value function, so there is no solution here either.

**Conclusion:** There are 2 intersection points between $|x-5|$ and $|3x-2|$. They are $(\frac{-3}{2},\frac{13}{2})$ and $(\frac{7}{4},\frac{13}{4})$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the plus-minus signs of both the equations. In the above you have considered only one. You should solve:

`$\begin{alignat*}{1}
-x-5 &= 3x-2\\
-x-5 &= -(3x-2)\\
-(-x-5) &= 3x-2\\
-(-x-5) &= -(3x-2)
\end{alignat*}$

Comment: The solutions seem to be puzzling me though. Hopefully I'm right in assuming I can split these up into piecewise functions. Firstly, is the right half of the red line supposed to be $-(-x-5)$?  That would justify its slope but not its y-intercept. And that would make the left half $-x-5$, but it has a y-intercept of +5. What gives? In addition, regardless of their functions, the right half of the red line will never intersect with the right half of the blue line, so how can they all have solutions?

Comment: First of all dont think geometrically, do the algebra and write precise equations. i.e. Note that when you write $|x-5|$, it means either $x-5$ or $-x+5$. Similar possibilities for $|3x-1|$. This gives you 4 equations (4 lines geometrically).

Comment: This is fine for me in that sense, but, intuitively, how are they solutions if they don't seem to ever visually intersect?

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the general step without making graph :*

Step 01: For solving equations of the form $|ax+b|=|cx+d|$ ,open the mod then equation looks like ax+b=cx-d  then solve for x co ordinate, after solving you get $x=\frac{d-b}{a-c}$

Step 02: for getting Y co ordinate, put Y  = | $ax_1 + b$ | where $x_1$ = $\frac{d-b}{a-c}$

Step03: Repeat the step 1 and step 2 on this equation $|ax+b|=|cx+d|$ by replacing b by "-b" and  also replace a by "-a"
then your expression become $|-ax-b|=|cx+d|$ and open the mod then expression looks like -ax-b=cx+d

by following step 1 and apply step 2 to get y co-ordinate.

Then you will be able to get your 2 solution.

*How I make this step* = just observing 3 things

1. Lines will intersect always in 1st and 2nd quadrants so if they intersect in 3rd and 4 th quadrant without mod then still value of x will be same so we remove mod without changing anything as mentioned in step 01
2. making slope +ve to -ve according to  get another intersection of These lines as with mod we get another intersection which can be get by changing the sign of one of line and open the mod directly
3. the value Y will always +ve so we put mod on it

Answer (score -1):

Just square both side, and you will get a quadratic equation. Factorise it, and you'll get the answer.